# Getting the last 6 months data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

i had data frame which contain many row. Here it is:

```
library(lubridate)

date_ <- date(seq(ymd_h("2020-01-01-00"), ymd_h("2021-03-31-23"), by = "hours"))
hour_ <- hour(seq(ymd_h("2020-01-01-00"), ymd_h("2021-03-31-23"), by = "hours"))

game1 <- sort(round(runif(length(date_), 10, 50), 0), decreasing = TRUE)
game2 <- sort(round(runif(length(date_), 20, 100), 0), decreasing = TRUE)
game3 <- sort(round(runif(length(date_), 30, 150), 0), decreasing = TRUE)
game4 <- sort(round(runif(length(date_), 40, 200), 0), decreasing = TRUE)

game_data <- data.frame(date_, hour_, game1, game2, game3, game4)
```

I just want to subset game_data to get all the last 6 months data. How do i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last 6 months of data from the `max` date in the data ?

You can try -

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

result <- subset(game_data, date_ > max(date_) %m-% months(6))
```

Or with `dplyr` -

```
result <- game_data %>% filter(date_ > max(date_) %m-% months(6))
```

Comment: Nice. This is the solution that i need